# DOS line endings in Cygwin break emacs

Tags: spacemacs, microsoft-windows, cygwin

I started using Spacemacs with GUI Emacs on Windows and all was fine apart from using Tramp with plink so I decided to use Cygwin with emacs-32 (and Spacemacs) because there is proper ssh there.
Now everything is a bit quicker and Tramp works really solidly.

But now (in emacs-w32) there are DOS line endings in the game (meaning `^M`) and that breaks some stuff. One example would be that a version check of ipython throws an error because the string containing the version also contains the line ending.

I thought that Emacs makes these line endings transparent (I still don't see them in GUI Emacs on Windows. So what's happening here? Is it because Cygwin is a weird combination of DOS and UNIX and is inconsistent in using just one type of line ending?

Comment: yeah I run into the same problem: `Error (use-package): python :init: Invalid version syntax: ‘5.1.0^M’` - I wonder if this is specific to the python layer?

Answer (score 3):

Just encountered this myself today when switching to cygwin.

The reason it didn't work for me was that the python layer in spacemacs only strips `\n` when looking up the ipython version on init.

The binaries supplied from [python.org](http://python.org) uses windows line endings to work well with the windows cmd line. This breaks the version check in the setup of the python layer.

Uninstalling the [python.org](http://python.org) version and using the python packages supplied with cygwin solves the problem in my case.

Will submit a ticket to spacemacs about it, but thought this might help anyone encountering the same issue.